# NoClassDefFoundError on executing AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sdk, android-studio

I have an AsyncTask in my android app. That works fine for android 19 (or later), but when i try to run app and execute this asynctask in android 15, returned this exception:

```
9692-10041/com.test.debug E/ACRA﹕ com.test.debug fatal error : java.util.Objects[]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects[]
        at com.test.ContentActivity.startContentTask(ContentActivity.java:181)
        at com.test.ContentActivity.onCreate(ContentActivity.java:161)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4645)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1940)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:129)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1153)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4516)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I added `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'` in build.gradle.

(In this AsyncTask, I'm using HttpClient and called a web service)

Comment: `Objects` is a class introduced with Java 7. Surely this is the reason.

Comment: Typo? `Object` instead of `Objects`

Comment: Objects is added in API19, so earlier versions don´t work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `java.util.Objects` has been introduced in Java 7 so it doesn't exist in earlier versions of the Android platform.

However, since `Objects` is a utility class with no instances, making an array of that type quite useless, it is a virtual certainty that the real error is in referring to this class instead of `java.lang.Object`.